# First new line symbol is gone from Model on ASP.NET MVC side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

[image]

From browser we send post request with first new line in CheckFooterTemplate field but on server side it is gone

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found StringTrimModelBinder that's it